# Nesting in bayesian inference

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, nested-models

I am currently trying to develop a model that takes into account different data sets that are not directly comparable. 
More specifically, my model needs to describe the amount of a drug in the blood, and I have given the concentrations in the blood at different times, but also the concentration in different organs at the end of the study. 
My model describing this process has variables that are not directly dependent on the organs and variables that are directly dependent on the organs (i.e. partition coefficients).
The problem here is that I don't value a data point in the organs the same as a data point in the blood, but I can't express this via a weight only blood data point> organ data point.
In a frequentist framework, I would solve this by nesting my fitting algorithms, i.e.
my outer fitting algorithm would only fit the variables that do not directly depend on the organ data. The inner algorithm would then optimise the remaining variables for each proposed parameter set of the outer fitting algorithm.
However, I also wanted to try this in a Bayesian framework, but I'm not sure if there is a good way to translate this nesting into a Bayesian framework.

I have already tried two different approaches:

1. Nesting the MCMC: At each step of the outer MCMC, I run a new inner MCMC on the remaining parameters and I randomly draw the remaining parameters from the resulting distribution.
   However, this didn't really converge and the Markov chain part of the outer MCMC may be questionable.
2. MCMC on all parameters at once: I have simply done the MCMC on all parameters at once, but have a different distribution (i.e. a different sigma) for the organ data. However, I lose the desired ordering of blood data vs organ data and the results are not really convincing.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?
Thanks :)